# How to break a long integer into mobile phone number?

Tags: java

I had type a code to print the output of a number into mobile phone format...

But it shows error related to method using in this code ... please help to remove the error ... and if their are alternative methods then please mention .. 
here the code is

```
public class PrintAddressFormat
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String name,address; 
        long phonenum; 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the Name : ");
        name=in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter the Address : \n");
        address=in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter the Phone number : \n");
        phonenum=in.nextLong();

        System.out.println("**********************************************");
        System.out.println("Name : "+name);
        System.out.println("Address : "+address);
        System.out.println("Phone Number : "+ phoneFormat(phonenum));
        System.out.println("**********************************************");

       void phoneFormat(long temp)
        {
            long rem1=temp%10000;
            temp=temp/10000;
            long rem2=temp%100;
            temp=temp/100;
            System.out.println(temp+"-"+rem2+"-"+rem1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Why not try using String as phone number type?

Comment: A phone number is not an integer. It has leading `0` which matter and sometimes `+` and spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MaskFormatter to do this. See code below

```
String phoneMask= "###-###-####";
String phoneNumber= "1234567890";

MaskFormatter maskFormatter= new MaskFormatter(phoneMask);
maskFormatter.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
maskFormatter.valueToString(phoneNumber) ;
System.out.println(maskFormatter.valueToString(phoneNumber));
```